# Is there a way to enable RecyclerView Touch Events back?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, android-touch-event

I'm disabling RecyclerView Touch Events by:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

When I want to enable it back <s>I'm just changing return statement to false,</s> **I'm adding OnItemTouchListener to RecyclerView again which returns false this time**, like I've found on Stackoverflow. Unfortunately after doing this I can't swipe recycler items or scroll RecyclerView. How to enable Touch Events back?

Comment: "When I want to enable it back I'm just changing return statement to false" - based on your code that is not possible as you don't have a `boolean` as the return variable you can mutate.  Why not create and hold a reference to your `SimpleOnItemTouchListener` and use : `RecyclerView::addOnItemTouchListener(listener)` & `RecyclerView::removeOnItemTouchListener(listener)` - it seems more explicit to only add and remove it when required and name the variable accordingly i.e `itemTouchConsumer`

Comment: I've correct my statement about returning false.
Your method seems simple and very logic! I'm going to do this way as soon as I get home.

Comment: Now I see that adding a new OnItemTouchListener with "return false" doesn't change anything because the old OnItemTouchListener still consumes clicks! I though that adding a new OnItemTouchListener removes the old one.